# Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder SQL MIN from joined table as aggregate field in subquery

Tags: join, doctrine-orm, field, aggregate, query-builder

I have a database table with rentals and a table with prices (One-To-Many). I tried to get the minimal price of all fetched rows from my RentalPrice table and save the value in my Rental Entity.

But I get every time a Syntax Error (Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'n2:). What I'm doing wrong?

Is there a problem with result set mapping?
Should the addSelect be more explicit?

```
$qb->select('Rental',  'RentalPrices')
   ->from('Rental\Entity\Rental', 'Rental')    
   ->leftJoin('Rental.prices', 'RentalPrices')
   ->addSelect('MIN(RentalPrices.priceperweek) AS Rental.minprice');
```

My "Rental" entity has a column where I can safe the data.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $minprice = null;
```

**UPDATE**

```
$qb->select('Rental',  'RentalPrices')
   ->from('Rental\Entity\Rental', 'Rental')    
   ->leftJoin('Rental.prices', 'RentalPrices')
   ->addSelect('MIN(RentalPrices.priceperweek) AS minprice');
```

But now the result is:

```
Object
minprice
```

So my question is now how can I do the hydration or mapping? I want the value of minprice in my entity Rental.minprice.